# Cannot load img_lib from custom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i am having this problem when trying to load img_library inside my custom library's constructor. It gives me this error:

*Unable to load the requested file: helpers/img_lib_helper.php*

This is my code:

```
  class Filemanager{

            private $_CI;

            public function __construct(){
                $this->_CI =& get_instance();
                $this->_CI->load->library('img_lib');
            }
       .....
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder why the error points to helpers/ ? I think it must point to libraries/ am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed. Did you overload your `Loader` class?
What version of Codeigniter are you using? I know that in 2.2 you should load `image_lib` and not `img_lib`.